# Which word has the same pronuncation as the word "may"?

Tags: homophones

What is the homophone of the word *may*? I can't find one real dictionary of homophones, nor is there an answer through Google.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: I can't think of any. Neither can Wiktionary. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rhymes:English:-e%C9%AA

Comment: Ooh, ooh. How about meigh? The sound made by a genetic cross between a cow and a horse :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo +1 Well, *may* be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since a homophone is [defined](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/homophone) as (my emphasis):

> Each of two or more words having the same pronunciation but different meanings, origins, ***or*** spelling, e.g., *new* and *knew*.
>   (Oxford Dictionaries)

I guess that means that *may* ("allowed to"), *May* (the month), and *Mae* (the female name) are homophones.

Comment: In some extreme dialects (Tori Amos-style warbling comes to mind), even ‘me’ could be a homophone, or at least a near-homophone, to ‘may’.

Answer (score 1):

**Mais** oui monsieur, my name is **Mae**.

Answer (score 0):

Note that homophones are tricky. Since the definition relies on pronunciation, and that varies with dialect, words that are homophones in one part of the English-speaking world may not be in others. Sometimes even in nearby places.

For example, where I live [*cot* and *caught*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot-caught_merger#Cot.E2.80.93caught_merger) are homophones. Even that statement is a bit extreme, as I had some friends growing up who said them differently, but I do not. I live on one of the "in transition" dots on the map at the given link. Likewise, [*pen* and *pin*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pin-pen_merger) are essentially homophones when I say them, but not when my wife does.